# Filter records from a join table by both relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, graphql

```rb
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  has_many :products, through: :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :product
end

class Products < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end
```

Is it possible to define associations so that after the relation is eager loaded, the list of records from joining table is filtered by the `Package` before accessing them from the `Product` side? Example:

```rb
last_package = Package.eager_load(:products).last
last_product = last_package.products.last
last_product.items

# here instead of getting the list of all items, that belong to the last_product
# I want to get only items, that belong to both last_package and last_product
```

IMPORTANT!

It should be a relation or a scope without arguments, I need it to for the [GraphQL AssociationLoader](https://gist.github.com/palkan/03eb5306a1a3e8addbe8df97a298a466#gistcomment-3205483).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `Item.where(package_id: last_package, product_id: last_product)`?

Comment: @engineersmnky, no, it should be a one-stop solution, so that I can do `Package.eager_load(:products).sample.products.sample.items` and always have a correct result with records filtered from both sides.

Comment: While there exists a hack to do this, it is a very bad idea to do so. Could you tell us why do you have "no argument" requirement - it is possible you're chasing a non-viable solution when a more obvious solution exists in higher level design

Comment: @BroiSatse it is hard to explain. I have a graphql app, and I need to define types and their fields as `Packages::Type.products` >> `Products::Type.count_grouped_items + Products::Type.items` >> `Items::Type.id` to be able to fetch data using the query: `query { packages { products { countGroupedItems items { id } } }`. countGroupedItems will contain the number of items that belong to the unique combination of package+product.

Comment: @BroiSatse I'll define separate relations for my case, so the main ones will be okay. Do you have a hack for this?

Comment: @taras - The hack is to combine `includes` with `joins` and `where`. In presence of join, `includes` will preload association based on the joined results, which however might be filtered with additional `where` clauses - causing only some of the records to be loaded into association. Note that that causes a number of weird behaviours - for example `size` and `count` return different values fur such incorrectly preloaded association and it generally misbehaves in so many interesting ways... Would be much better to question your model structure. Not posting an answer as I'd need to downvote it